# CollectionView don't update visible cell

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

Good afternoon!

Faced with this problem, there is a collection in which cells in the whole screen
the cell is configured with data,
and there are events inside the cell that make the collection reload,
it is not possible to make a check, if the cell is now visible, it is not necessary to update it completely, but only part of the data, I do not yet understand how to do it, can someone be able to prompt?!))

Test project))

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionViwe: UICollectionView!

    let dataSource = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionViwe.isPagingEnabled = true
        collectionViwe.register(Cell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataSource.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! Cell
        let text = String(dataSource[indexPath.row])
        if cell.label.text != text {
            cell.label.text = text
            cell.label.backgroundColor = .random()
        }

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return view.frame.size
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return .zero
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }

}

class Cell: UICollectionViewCell {

    let label = UILabel()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        label.backgroundColor = .red
        addSubview(label)
        label.frame = CGRect(x: 36, y: 36, width: 200, height: 100)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}


extension CGFloat {
    static func random() -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max)
    }
}

extension UIColor {
    static func random() -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(red:   .random(),
                       green: .random(),
                       blue:  .random(),
                       alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing stops you from updating outlets inside the Cell to show your new data. It's not necessary to reload the CollectioView or it's cell

Comment: i have a uiviewcontroller inside uicollectionviewcell, and if basket change state empty(true/false) is should show basket indicator inside uiviewcontrollelr, UIViewControlelr have observer to basket state